# Apache Ant java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, apache, ant

Soy nuevo en `Ant`, estoy realizando un programa `client-server` con `Eclipse`, estoy usando librerías externas: `JMapViewer-1.14.1.jar`, el server funciona correctamente el client me lanza un error.

Al ejecutar desde el terminal de `Ubuntu` :

```
ant clean compile jar run
```

Recibo un `error` en el target `run`:

```
     [java] Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
     [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openstreetmap/gui/jmapviewer/JMapViewer
     [java]     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
     [java]     at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
     [java]     at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
     [java]     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
     [java]     at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
     [java]     at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openstreetmap.gui.jmapviewer.JMapViewer
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
     [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
     [java]     ... 7 more
     [java] Java Result: 1
```

Mi file build.xml:

```
<project>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build" />
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="build/classes" />
        <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement path="/home/bryan/Scrivania/Libraries/JMapViewer-1.14.1.jar" />
                <pathelement path="/home/bryan/Scrivania/Libraries/mail.jar" />
                <pathelement path="/home/bryan/Scrivania/Libraries/postgresql-42.0.0.jre6.jar" />
            </classpath>

        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="jar">

        <mkdir dir="build/jar" />
        <jar destfile="build/jar/UI.jar" basedir="build/classes">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="UI" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="run">
        <java jar="build/jar/UI.jar" fork="true" />
    </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error de JNI no tiene nada que ver con Ant. Es un error de ejecución de tu programa.

Quiere decir que estás usando una librería de Java que se conecta a librerías nativas, no se encuentran dichas librerías nativas (dll en Windows o so en linux).

Revisa las instrucciones de instalación de las librerías para saber qué librerías nativas necesitas tener en tu máquina.

Comment: Lo raro es que con el server no me da este error.